# Parse error when changing column to date

Tags: sql, h2

I have a table that I import from a `CSV` file which contains a column with dates. The format of the date is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Some of the records are empty. I try to make the table aware the column are dates and issue the command

```
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN "due-date" DATE;
```

But I receive thiserror message:

> ALTER TABLE ISSUES ALTER COLUMN "due-date" DATE; Cannot parse "DATE"
>   constant ; SQL statement:
>   -- row #38 (.....)

Row #38 is the first time that "due-date" is empty. My interpretation is that the parsing works well until it reaches an empty cell.

How can I get H2 to accept empty values and just make them NULL? I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE ISSUES ALTER COLUMN "due-date" DATE NULL;
```

But I still get the same error message.

Comment: I'd try: Alter table add new column. Copy data. Remove old column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try first converting empty string to null, and *then* alter the column:

```
UPDATE ISSUES SET "due-date" = NULL WHERE "due-date" = '';
ALTER TABLE ISSUES ALTER COLUMN "due-date" DATE NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest *adding* a `due-date2 DATE` column, and use an `UPDATE` statement to copy all values over.

You can then drop the `due-date VARCHAR` column and rename `due-date2` back to `due-date`.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the "-" characters from the column values using replace() command
Nulls will not cause a problem here
Then try executing Alter Column statement